# "publish" to mqtt broker using raspbian doesn't work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I'm trying to publish to thinkgspeak.com values from a sensor attached to my raspberry pi. 
The code doesn't produce any error but results are not published.
This is a simple snippet:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

channelID = "******"
apiKey = "******"
topic = "channel/" + channelID + "/publish/" + apiKey
mqttHost = "mqtt.thingspeak.com"

tTransport = "tcp"
tPort = 1883
tTLS = None

pmt_2_5 = 2
pmt_10 = 4

aqi_2_5 = 6
aqi_10 = 12

tPayload = "field1=" + str(pmt_2_5) + "field2=" + str(pmt_10) + \
        "field3=" + str(pmt_2_5) + \
        "field4=" + str(pmt_10)

publish.single(topic, payload=tPayload, qos=0,
      hostname="mqtt.thingspeak.com",
      port=tPort, tls=tTLS,
      protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311,
      transport=tTransport)
```

Comment: You seem to be missing any authentication (username/password) which all the thingspeak doc does imply you will need

Comment: I'm really struggling with this and I cannot find anything about authentication, for instance I found: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/publishtoachannelfeed.html

Comment: Look at point 3 here https://uk.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/use-desktop-mqtt-client-to-publish-to-a-channel.html

Comment: @hardillb I have created an auth parameter auth = {
     'username' :  "*******",
      'password' : "*******"
}
to be passed in the method: publish.single(topic, payload=tPayload, hostname=mqttHost, port=tPort, tls=tTLS, transport=tTransport, auth=auth) but problem persists.